# top-left corner pixel must be either opaque white or transparent

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am trying to make an image to 9-patch image.

I converted `a.png` into `a.9.png`. However, it shows this error below:

```
top-left corner pixel must be either opaque white or transparent.
```

[image]

The `a.png` file, the background is transparent. But the editor of Android Studio seems like it doesn't detect the transparent background but it displays black background instead.

Here is the png file(It's a white image with transparent background):

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Can you upload the `a.png` image?

Comment: @Tommy I added the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because of the image tool.

I used this [photopea](https://www.photopea.com). And it seems like it can't convert correctly.

So, I reckon some applications have little flaws.

I tried with [pixlr editor](https://pixlr.com/editor/) and it worked fine.

If you have photoshop program, it's the best.